# Ошибка: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! Пишу первую программу на с++ и не пойму, почему высвечивается ошибка:

> error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
> error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   cout << "Hello world" << endl;  //тут ошибка
}
```

Ошибка в строке №3.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: std::cout очевидно

Comment: Или добавьте перед main

    using namespace std;

Comment: Спасибо всем

Comment: А ещё неплохо было бы что-то возвращать из этой функции. Ну так, на всякий случай)

Answer (score 6):

Вам необходимо определить пространство имен `std`. Все идентификаторы стандартной библиотеки C++ определяются в пространстве имен с таким именем. Пространство имен определяет область видимости идентификаторов. Определить можно непосредственно при выводе “Hello world” (данная запись называется непосредственное уточнение идентификатора):

```
std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

Есть также иной способ: можете написать перед функцией `main()`:

```
using namespace std;
```

Эта запись используется чаще всего (для простоты, в коротких листингах). Она означает, что после её выполнения все идентификаторы пространства `std` доступны так, как если бы они были объявлены глобально. Однако не стоит злоупотреблять такой записью, поскольку в сложных программах она может привести к периодическим конфликтам имен, к непредсказуемым последствиям из-за правил перегрузки.

Еще вариант использования некоего пространства имен. На примере показано как можно получить локальную возможность пропуска префикса `std::` для `cout` и `endl`:

```
using std::cout; 
using std::endl;
```